# Convert hex to BigInteger

Tags: java

I am trying to convert hex to Big Integer. Basically I have 32 characters = 16 bytes, so I expect that `BigInteger` also has 16 bytes, but for some cases, i.e. hex starts with 99.. it generates additional byte with 0. I'm using

```
new BigInteger(hex, 16)
```

How can I avoid the 17th byte?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to follow exactly what the problematic case is. It would be *much* easier to help you if you'd post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, i.e. with input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: Due to Java's signedness, any value that starts with `80` or higher will result in an "extra" byte when performing `toByteArray()`.

Comment: Kayaman, so there is no other way than have this extra 0? :(

Comment: Actually you may have less bytes than 16 as well if your hex starts with `000` to `007`. If it's some kind of hash function, there's `1/512` chance. Test such case as well.

Answer (score 2):

From [BigInteger's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) :

> Immutable arbitrary-precision integers. All operations behave as if
>   BigIntegers were represented in two's-complement notation (like Java's
>   primitive integer types).

And [description of the constructor you are using](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String,%20int)) :

> Translates the String representation of a BigInteger in the specified
>   radix into a BigInteger. The String representation consists of an
>   optional minus or plus sign followed by a sequence of one or more
>   digits in the specified radix. The character-to-digit mapping is
>   provided by Character.digit. The String may not contain any extraneous
>   characters (whitespace, for example).

This means that if you call it with `new BigInteger( "99000000000000000000000000000000", 16)` you will get a BigInteger which holds that value (which is a positive value) as if it were represented in two's-complement notation. That positive value in two's complement does not fit in 16 bytes so of course the end result is 17 bytes long.

You are guaranteed to get a BigInteger with a maximun of 16 bytes if you call it with values between (both included):

```
 - new BigInteger( "7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16)
 - new BigInteger("-80000000000000000000000000000000", 16)
```

Any value higher than the first or lower than the last will result in more than 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The first byte cannot start with an `1` bit, because that would mean a negative number. They prevent this by adding an additional zero byte at the start of the array. This function will check and chop off that byte:

```
public static byte[] signedToUnsignedBytes(byte[] myBytes) {
    return myBytes.length > 1 && myBytes[0] == 0
        ? Arrays.copyOfRange(myBytes, 1, myBytes.length)
        : myBytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A byte value of over 127 cannot be represented with Java's `byte`, since they're signed (well, they *can* but Java will consider them as negative numbers).

When `BigInteger` converts the value to a byte array, it will add a 0 byte in front to distinguish a positive value from a negative value.

This results in the fact that `128` will become `[0][-128]`, whereas `-128` will become just `[-128]`.

If you intend to store the resulting bytes as an unsigned 128-bit value, you can just chop off the first element of the array, e.g. `byte[] sanitizedBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(myBytes, 1, 16);`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using `BigInteger` for the sole purpose to convert the hex string of fixed length to the `byte[]` array. This can be done in another way, for example, using `ByteBuffer` class:

```
static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
    bb.asIntBuffer().put((int) Long.parseLong(s.substring(0, 8), 16))
                    .put((int) Long.parseLong(s.substring(8, 16), 16))
                    .put((int) Long.parseLong(s.substring(16, 24), 16))
                    .put((int) Long.parseLong(s.substring(24), 16));
    return bb.array();
}
```

Or somewhat simpler in Java-8 using `Long.parseUnsignedLong()`:

```
static byte[] toByteArray8(String s) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
    bb.asLongBuffer().put(Long.parseUnsignedLong(s.substring(0, 16), 16))
                     .put(Long.parseUnsignedLong(s.substring(16), 16));
    return bb.array();
}
```

This way you should not care about corner cases (you will always get 16 bytes even for `"000...000"` string) and likely will have less heap allocations. Sample usage:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toByteArray("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")));
// [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toByteArray("80000000000000000000000000000000")));
// [-128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toByteArray("123FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")));
// [18, 63, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toByteArray("007FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")));
// [0, 127, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toByteArray("00000000000000000000000000000001")));
// [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```